# Using Java regex : extract a portion of text from another String

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract string "**data**" from this container string "**<%= @my_secrets['data'] %>**" using java regex.
Another example below

```
String input = "<%= @my_secrets['/abc/PQ-XYZ/1234/'] %>";
String expectedOutut = "/abc/PQ-XYZ/1234/";
```

Can anyone suggest, how can I achieve this, using single regular expression matcher.

Before extraction I also need to ensure the container String is in format "**<%= @my_secrets['some data here'] %>**" then only extract.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are certain you can isolate your input text to the starting string in your question, you might be able to use a regex `String#replaceAll` one-liner approach:

```java
String input = "<%= @my_secrets['/abc/PQ-XYZ/1234/'] %>";
if (input.matches("<%= @my_secrets\\['.*'\\] %>")) {
    String output = input.replaceAll(".*'(.*?)'.*", "$1");
    System.out.println(output);  // /abc/PQ-XYZ/1234/
}
else {
    System.out.println("input does not match required format");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Before extraction I also need to ensure the container String is in format "<%= @my_secrets[''] %>" then only extract. How can I check that using regex ?

Comment: When I run this it always go else block

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to escape the `[` and `]` brackets in the regex pattern being passed to `String#matches`.  It works now.

Comment: input.matches("<%= @my_secrets\\['.*'\\] %>")   The escape char \\ at the closing square bracket  is redundant, as reported by IDE. This solution worked like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you care performance:
Remember that matches and replaceAll are regex's - so in case calling one by one

```
input.matches
```

and then

```
input.replaceAll
```

your're making at least two time compile

```
  Pattern.compile(regex)
```

So - compile once - and then use it

```
    static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<%= @my_secrets\\['(.*)'\\] %>");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<%= @my_secrets['/abc/PQ-XYZ/1234/'] %>";
    Matcher matcher =  p.matcher(input);

    if  (matcher.find()) {
        //System.out.println(matcher.group());
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceFirst("$1"));
    }
}
```

and be carefull with .* - [lazy trap](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazytrap) - it also can kill your app/server

Answer (score -1):

```
String cleaned = input.replaceAll(".*?'([^']+).*", "$1");
```

should do it